# Voice lessons for children

Tags: learning, voice, lessons

My 9 year old daughter is interested in singing. I've been thinking about getting her voice lessons. Is she too young? When is the ideal age to start vocal lessons?

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's much more important to get her **singing** than to get her singing **lessons**. She can sing in a childrens' choir, form a band, etc.

There are so many different things one can do with singing, and early formal study as (say) a classical singer could (maybe! not necessarily) be counterproductive if she ends up wanting to front a band. Or vice versa.

But well-rounded musical **experience** can never start too early or be too varied.